# How to give write access permission to Asp.net Core ContentRoot path on a IIS Web Server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

My Asp.net Core 3 application is trying to write to a log file in the ContentRoot directory on an IIS Web server but I'm getting an Access Denied exception. How can I give write access to this folder? I've tried several solutions giving permission to different users without success. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Try to write to a log only folder. 2) What users did you try? You might get some ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0

Comment: What you are suggesting is probably a little dangerous. Would you reconsider?  How about picking a different folder for logs, which is not in ContentRoot?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have seen IUSR user on some web pages for example. The application will be moved to Azure but for the moment in Dev environment, I'm trying to store the logs somewhere. I also tried %systemroot%\Inetpub\Logs without success. Where would you store the logs?

Comment: Due to the fact that by default AspDotNet core doesn’t has the built-in functionality of writing a log file, which third-library did you use to write a log file in Asp.Net core web application? Like the below libraries, they usually support to write a log file to ContentRoot, which is the root directory of the web application by default.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file
Besides, wwwroot is the default web root of web application. It supports static file writing.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I use my own logging library. The problem is coming from the IIS permission to ContentRoot. For example, I will get an access denied exception with the following example:
System.IO.File.WriteAllText ($"{MyWebHostEnv.ContentRootPath}\\Test.txt", "Hello World") ;

Comment: Try to change the IIS application Identity to an administrator account. Alternatively, `wwwroot` folder might be another choice to write a file. Did you try another folder to store logs? such as D:\logs.text

Comment: Nope, Access Denied on all paths.